# html - документ, изображения не отображаются в браузере

Tags: php, javascript, html, ubuntu, vim

в браузере отображаются только (зеленая иконка и alt"")));
сижу в vim из под ubuntu;
 новичек, вопрос банален , заранее спасибо за ответ.

```html
<div class="hi">
 <p><img src="home/gleb/images/p21111729.png width="100" height="200" 
  alt="Иллюстрация" align="left" </p>
```

Comment: ух, такую мелочь нужно за км видеть и пропускать только после 5 безсонных ночей под кофе!
2 ошибки 
1) закрой ковычки у img
2) закрой тег img

Comment: еще 1
3) align атрибут абзацa (<p>)
и мини недочет (это больше из моей практики)
в абзац пихать только инлайны, а img блок

Comment: @DemoGosha спасибо на указаные ошибки синтаксиса , но таковых в редакторе нет , это сенсор подвел

Comment: @DemoGosha насчет атрибута согласен , поэксперементирую , спасибо